# Calculate the expected value, its modulus and the variance

Tags: probability

> Given is the random variable $X: \begin{pmatrix}
> -\epsilon & 0 & \epsilon\\  \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2} & 1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} & \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2} \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Calculate $E(X), E(|X|)$ and $var(X)$

I'm not sure if I did it correctly, especially about the modulus?

$$E(X)=-\epsilon \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}+0 \cdot(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2})+\epsilon \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}= -\frac{1}{2\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}=0$$

$$E(|X|) = \left| -\epsilon \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}+0 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}) + \epsilon \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2} \right |= \left| -\frac{1}{2\epsilon} + \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \right|$$

$$var(X) = (-\epsilon-0)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}+(0-0)^2 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2})+(\epsilon-0)^2 \cdot (\frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}) = \epsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}+\epsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X\right|\right]=\sum_x \left|x\right|\cdot\Pr\left(X=x\right)$, and not $\left|\sum_x x\cdot\Pr\left(X=x\right)\right|$. Other than this it looks good to me.

Comment: in this particular case $X^2=\epsilon |X|$

Comment: @Guy Then I get $$E(|X|)=|-\epsilon|\cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}+|0|\cdot (1-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2})+|\epsilon|\cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}=|-\epsilon| \cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}+|\epsilon|\cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}$$ but I don't think I could simplify that further?

Comment: @cnmesr I suppose $\epsilon>0$, so you could simplify it even further.

Comment: @Guy I don't see how? $$\frac{|-\epsilon|}{2\epsilon^2}+\frac{|\epsilon|}{2\epsilon^2}=\frac{|-\epsilon|+|\epsilon|}{2\epsilon^2} \geq \frac{|\epsilon-\epsilon|}{2\epsilon^2}$$

Comment: What is $\left|-1\right|$? What is $\left|1\right|$? Now replace $1$ with $\epsilon$...